# Building a Neural Network using Keras on R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to build and train a neural network using R. I am using the Keras package to do this.

**This is what I have written so far:**

```
# Select library

library(readr)
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)

# Select data and transform into matrix
setwd("~/R")
data.set <- read.csv('SEBinary.csv')
data.set <- as.matrix(data.set)

# Remove column names

dimnames(data.set) = NULL   

# Split data into training and test subsets

set.seed(123)
indx <- sample(2,
               nrow(data.set),
               replace = TRUE,
               prob = c(0.9,0.1))

# Split input variable from output/target variable

x_train <- data.set[indx == 1,1:15]
x_test <- data.set[indx == 2,1:15]

y_test_actual <- data.set[indx == 2, 16]

y_train <- to_categorical(data.set[ indx == 1, 16])
y_test <- to_categorical(data.set[indx == 2, 16])

# Creating the model

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  # Network architecture
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(15)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "softmax") %>%
  # Backpropagation
  compile(
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = 'adam',
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  )
```

**Everything works fine until I get to:**

```
y_train <- to_categorical(data.set[ indx == 1, 16])
y_test <- to_categorical(data.set[indx == 2, 16])
```

**At that point, I receive the following error and information:**

```
Error: Python module tensorflow.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  7 2020, 19:46:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1
```

I do not understand this error because I have repeatedly installed Keras, Tensor Flow and Miniconda but it persists nonetheless. I have also tried downloading the packages from Github as an alternative.

Comment: Could you please try `remotes::install_github("rstudio/keras")` and then re start `R`!

Comment: I have tried it but receive the same error.